# How can I redirect users to the app if it's installed otherwise to the playstore/appstore like spotify?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I want to redirect users to either playstore/appstore or the app as soon as they click on "Get the App" on my website. How are websites like spotify doing it? I already have a custom scheme and I've tried using the setTimeOut method but apparently that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: you can use `Firebase Dynamic Links` https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links